# Swift 3 migration error in my code

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am getting error in my code

```
func dataFromHexadecimalString(_ key:String) -> NSString? {

    let trimmedString = key.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<> ")).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")


    let regex: NSRegularExpression?
    do {
        regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[0-9a-f]*$", options: .caseInsensitive)
    } catch _ as NSError {
        regex = nil
    }
    let found = regex?.firstMatch(in: trimmedString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, trimmedString.characters.count))
    if found == nil || found?.range.location == NSNotFound || trimmedString.characters.count % 2 != 0 {
        return nil
    }


    let data = NSMutableData(capacity: trimmedString.characters.count / 2)

    //I am Getting error here i.e C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3
    for var index = trimmedString.startIndex; index < trimmedString.endIndex; index = Collection.index(after: Collection.index(after: index)) {
        let byteString = trimmedString.substring(with: (index ..< Collection.index(after: Collection.index(after: index))))
        let num = UInt8(byteString.withCString { strtoul($0, nil, 16) })
        data?.append([num] as [UInt8], length: 1)
    }

    let enCodedUTF8String = NSString(data: data! as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    return enCodedUTF8String

}
```

Getting error i.e `C-style for statement has been removed` 
see above comment in code

Comment: That is correct, the C-style for loop has been removed in Swift 3. I'd offer a fix for your code but I have no idea what it's doing. `Collection.index(after: Collection.index(after: index)))`??? What are you actually trying to do in your code? I have a feeling there is a much simpler more elegant way of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: It seems that the passed `key` parameter is a `String` created from a `Data` object. In the code you convert it back to `Data` and again back  to `String`. This is pretty cumbersome. You can create the hexadecimal representation from the original `Data` object in one line `let enCodedUTF8String = data.map{ String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell your code...

```
//I am Getting error here i.e C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3
for var index = trimmedString.startIndex; index < trimmedString.endIndex; index = Collection.index(after: Collection.index(after: index)) {
    let byteString = trimmedString.substring(with: (index ..< Collection.index(after: Collection.index(after: index))))
    let num = UInt8(byteString.withCString { strtoul($0, nil, 16) })
    data?.append([num] as [UInt8], length: 1)
}
```

Is iterating through the indices of the `trimmedString` but going 2? at a time?

If `index` is 0 (which it is to start) then the next index will be...

index after index after index... 2 after 1 after 0

So 2? Then 4? Then 6?

Then you're getting the substring from that index to the next index?

Then you're creating a `UInt8` from it and appending it to some data...

So...

I guess the easiest change would be a `while` loop...

```
var index = trimmedString.startIndex

while index < trimmedString.endIndex {
    // note I used the ... for the range to avoid the repeated... index after index after index
    let byteString = trimmedString.substring(with: (index ... Collection.index(after: index)))
    let num = UInt8(byteString.withCString { strtoul($0, nil, 16) })
    data?.append([num] as [UInt8], length: 1)

    // check the docs, there are easier ways of moving the index by more than one place.
    index = Collection(index, offsetBy: 2)
}
```

Something like that should work as an initial change.

**Much better approach suggested by @vadian**

As pointed out by @vadian there is a much simpler and more elegant way of doing all of this in one line of code...

```
let enCodedUTF8String = data.map{ String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
```

I thought that would be the case but I wasn't able to come up with it myself.